# Cap Resource Usage with Azure DataMovementLibrary Utility

Tags: c#, process, resources, azure-storage

I wrote a little utility to run a nightly backup from one of my servers to an Azure blob storage using the Data Movement Library (0.2.0): https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-0-2-0/

Nice library.  Anyway, I'm wondering if there's a way I can cap the resource usage of this?  I've got a few gig of data to transfer nightly but would rather have a "low spread" resource usage than "let's try to cram it all at once" scenario.

I suspect this is more of a generic process resource question than anything specific to this library, though I've never really had to worry about such elsewhere and would appreciate pointers.

My top priority is bandwidth: I'd like to keep a reasonable amount of open buffer on the network and limit the CPU usage to a reasonable amount.  RAM seems to take care of itself for the most part, but if I can easily cap that also, I'd go for it.

I currently fire this console app utility through the Windows Task Scheduler on a 2012R2 server.  The only lead I have is to possibly set up a launcher that creates a low priority Process to start the utility, but I'm unsure how that ties in with specific resources.

What else can I do to gain some control over the resources this would use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently DateMovement library doesn't support specifying resource usage cap, but can try to configure a lower TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks.  I had considered that, but wasn't sure if it would just put more resources to the lower number of parallel ops.  For example, if there's 100 units of resources available and 10 parallel ops, that gives me 10 units per op.  If I change the parallel count to 2, would it give me 50 units per op?  If this setting has actual effect on the amount of resources used, that would be a big help (I intended to test this... someday).

Comment: If you choose a lower ParrllelOperations, lower resources (CPU/memory/bandwidth) will be consumed, although it may not be linear.